# Text to columns in Excel - break into columns selectively

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to separate a single cell into columns but I just need the last 3 values (separated by "space") to be in the separated cells.

I have this (in one single column):

```
             Column A
Perdas com variações cambiais, líquidas 7 21.919.104 1.841,496
Perdas em ativos financeiros, líquidas 18 2.014.467 3.921.932
Perdas em empreendimentos conjuntos 30 2.185.679 3.011.998
Ganhos em empresas associadas, líquidos 33 (442.783.587) (210.273.584)
```

...and I need to have 4 columns (one for the text and the other 3 for the numeric values:

```
             Column A                     Column B    Column C        Column D
Perdas com variações cambiais, líquidas       7      21.919.104           1.841,496
Perdas em ativos financeiros, líquidas       18       2.014.467       3.921.932
Perdas em empreendimentos conjuntos          30       2.185.679       3.011.998
Ganhos em empresas associadas, líquidos      33    (442.783.587)   (210.273.584)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with some giant formulas but there aren't any helper columns to worry about. Assuming your same data is in the range `A1:A4`, these are the formulas for `B1:F1`. Copy / paste and drag them down.

Key Point: This assumes your data follows the format of the example. If there are less than 3 spaces in the raw data, it'll throw an error. You specified this was the case in the question, though, so I anticipate no issues.

Key Point: This assumes that a tilde `~` doesn't appear in your text. If it does, choose some other single character that doesn't. A pipe `|` is a common example.

```
B1 =LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",""))
C1 =TRIM(LEFT($A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1-2))))
D1 =LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1-2)))),FIND(" ",TRIM(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1-2)))))-1)
E1 =LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1-1)))),FIND(" ",TRIM(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1-1)))))-1)
F1 =TRIM(RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","~",$B1))))
```

Comment: (1) Wow; that uses the subexpression `LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","")` six times in four columns. That's really crying out for a helper column. (2) This will fail if the text contains any tildes (`~`).

Comment: @G-Man You're right on both points. (1) The problem I saw was that the helper column solution already posted requires some unknown number of helper columns which is not very robust. You could add that one value as a single helper column, though. (2) The user will have to pick *some* value that won't appear in their text. A pipe `|` works well, too. I'll clarify on both points.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a method that requires a bunch of “helper columns”. 
Pick a column that’s out of the way; e.g., `AA` or `Sheet2!A`
(I’ll assume that you’ve chosen `AA`), and enter this

```
=IFERROR(FIND(" ", $A1), "")
```

into cell `AA1`. 
This finds the character position within cell `A1` of the first space character. 
If there isn’t one, `FIND()` returns an error,
and `IFERROR()` replaces the error with an empty string.  Then enter

```
=IFERROR(FIND(" ", $A1, AA1+1), "")
```

into cell `AB1`.  (Note that the `A` has a `$` but the `AA` does not.) 
This finds the character position within cell `A1` of the second space character
(i.e., the first one after the one found by cell `AA1`). 
Again, error codes are replaced by empty cells. 
Drag this as far to the right as is necessary. 
(For example, if you don’t expect ever to have more than 24 words of actual text,
then you will have a maximum of 27 “words”, counting the three numbers. 
Therefore, there will be a maximum of 26 spaces,
so dragging out to `AZ1` should be enough.) 
If you drag `AB1` to `AZ1`, then `AZ1` should contain

```
=IFERROR(FIND(" ", $A1, AY1+1), "")
```

Then (assuming that you filled in the range `AA1:AZ1`, above),
enter the following in `X1`, `Y1`, and `Z1`:

- `X1` – `=LARGE(AA1:AZ1,3)`
- `Y1` – `=LARGE(AA1:AZ1,2)`
- `Z1` – `=LARGE(AA1:AZ1,1)`

These become the locations of the third-to-last, second-to-last, and last spaces in `A1`. 
For example:

[image]
  [<sup>(The image above is a link to a full-sized copy of itself.)</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylK4p.png)

where I have manually highlighted the values in the `AA`-`AZ` columns
that Excel selected for columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

Now it’s a “simple” matter of using these character positions to cut out the values
(text and numeric) that you want:

- `B1` – `=LEFT($A1, X1-1)`
- `C1` – `=MID($A1, X1+1, Y1-X1-1)`
- `D1` – `=MID($A1, Y1+1, Z1-Y1-1)`
- `E1` – `=RIGHT($A1, LEN(A1)-Z1)`

which equate to

- `B1` – everything (in `A1`) up to (but not including) the third-to-last space
- `C1` – everything between the third-to-last space and the second-to-last space
- `D1` – everything between the second-to-last space and the last space
- `E1` – everything after the last space

And, of course, drag everything down for as far as you have data.  E.g.,

[image]

If you have a space at the end of a line of input (after the last number)
or multiple spaces between any two numbers, this will break. 
If you get into that situation, I suggest that you research the `TRIM()` function.

Comment: Hello G-Man! Thank you so much for your help! I've already the results and they completly fit my need. In fact, for my database, both your and Engireer Toast's solutions retrieves basically the same output. Once I'll be continuing using such formulas, I'll become with feedback further.